# Travis-ci command "./gradlew build" exited with 1

Tags: travis-ci, gradlew

I am unable to build my Android application with Travis-ci.  It keeps failing with:

```
Travis-ci command "./gradlew build" exited with 1.
```

I have no idea what's causing this, and Travis-ci has no information on how to fix it!

Please advise,
Igor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I used the following **android components** section in my travis.yml file to solve the problem:

```
android:
  components:
    # Update Android SDK Tools
    - tools

    - build-tools-23.0.1
    - android-23

    # Support library
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-android-m2repository
```

Also, my **script** section has the following:

```
script:
- chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Seems to work now!

Comment: Not working for me !! any suggestions what I could be doing wrong -
`chmod: cannot access ‘./gradlew’: No such file or directory
The command "chmod +x ./gradlew" failed and exited with 1 during .`

Comment: @shadygoneinsane Did you set up a standard android proj. on Travis CI?

Comment: I am not sure what standard means here ! I have a native android studio project that m trying to set up on Travis CI

Comment: Assuming you followed this document fully:  https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/

Comment: Silly mistake was returning true before `- chmod +x ./gradlew`. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

hi i also have the same issue but the above solution was not working in my case.But if fix it by giving

```
before_install:
- chmod +x gradlew
```

After applying chmode on before_install i have resolved the issue.

Complete .travis.yml

```
language: android
android:
components:
# Uncomment the lines below if you want to
# use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
# - platform-tools
# - tools

# The BuildTools version used by your project
- build-tools-25.0.0

# The SDK version used to compile your project
- android-25


# Specify at least one system image,
# if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
- sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22
- sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-17

before_install:
- chmod +x gradlew
```

I hope this will help anyone who fail to get the solution from the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had to set the jdk in the second line to 8 and it works:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
android:
...
```